# Netezza does not do lazy evaluation of case statements?

Tags: sql, lazy-evaluation, netezza

I'm performing a computation which might contain division by 0, in which case I want the result to be an arbitrary value (55). To my surprise, wrapping the computation with a case statement did not do the job!

```
select case when 1=0 then 3/0 else 55 end
```

> ERROR HY000: Divide by 0

Why is that? Is there another workaround?

Comment: Maybe it does constant folding. What if you try against real data? (A similar thing happens in SQL Server with `select case when 1=0 then LOG(0) else 55 end`)

Comment: probably so - this failure is due to constants. I'll post the real query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, I was being inaccurate. This is the exact query that fails with "divide by 0":

`select case when min(baba) = 0 then 55 else sum(1/baba) end from t group by baba`

This looks like a lazy evaluation failure out of Netezza, as notice that I group by `baba`, so whenever baba is 0, it also means that `min(baba)` is 0, and the evaluation should have been gracefully stopped without ever getting to the `1/baba` term and failing on division by 0. Right? well, no.

**What I guess is the gotcha here and the reason for the failure** is that Netezza evaluates the rows terms before it can evaluate the aggregate terms. So it must evaluate `1/baba` and `baba` at every row, and only then can it evaluate the aggregate terms `min(baba)` and `sum(1/baba)`

so, the workaround (for me) was:  `select case when min(baba) = 0 then 55 else 1/min(baba) end from t group by baba`, which has the same meaning.

Comment: From my understanding of Netezza query processing is that aggregations are done on the host "after" the visibility/restrict engines on the FPGAs. This would explain why your query fails, and why as you see it evaluates and processes the rows on a rbr basis. From the way you wrote the query in the workaround it seems you moved that processing onto the "host" portion of Netezza, applying after aggregations.